# Convert to lowercase in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2014

I like my tsql in lowercase, but lots of times I run across examples where EVERYTHING IS CAPITALIZED for no reason.

There used to be a nice keyboard shortcut for ctrl-shift-l to tidy up this, but it seems to have stopped working in SSMS 2014 for some reason.

Anyone know what they changed it to?

Comment: that shortcut still works for selected text, if its not working for you tools>options>keyboard>reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Alex K. tools>options>keyboard>reset did the trick!

Answer (score 5):

The new shortcut is `ctrl+u`

The Documentation is very good, and also provides a mapping between old and new shortcuts: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server Management Studio v18.9.1, the default keyboard shortcut is showing as **Ctrl+Shift+L**

[image: SSMS Default Keyboard Shortcut for Edit.MakeLowercase]